# How can I make a button act like a menu?

Tags: android, android-button, android-menu

I am working on a simple application that is supposed to work on 800x480 tablet. Currently:
[][][][]
[][][][]
OOO

These are all buttons and they are working as expected. I, however, need to add menu items to the bottom-buttons. When clicked, menu items should pop up.

-Can I create a menu and place it at the bottom of the screen to replace those buttons? If so, could you show an example, cause I couldn't find any.

-Or, can I add menu items to these buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What You want is an OptionsMenu, if I understand You the right way. I could give You an example later, I am not at home. But for now, look at this example. If You follow this, You don´t need those buttons at the bottom.

[http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-beginner-tutorials/options-menu/](http://android-er.blogspot.de/2012/03/example-of-using-popupmenu.html)

if it is not clear, just let me know and I try to give You an example at the evening...

### EDIT

for custom menu, You could use PopUpMenu. I had not tried this for now, but I think it is a good solution

http://android-er.blogspot.de/2012/03/example-of-using-popupmenu.html

Comment: I tried OptionsMenu, made one and added to my project just to test it but it's no good for me. One needs to push the OptionsMenuButton to activate it. I need a menu to be activated when the user clicks a button at the bottom.

Comment: Hey Opiatefuchs, thanks it's what I've been looking for. I tried context menu while waiting for an answer, it didn't look good either. Popup menu looks great. Thanks again :)

Comment: glad that I could help You :)